# how to change the FusionWidgets UIComponent in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I'm using the ravis FusionWidgets component in flex to create guages.
I have a problem to change a guage in my program.
I build an mxml component with the guage like this:

"ns1:FusionWidgets id="myGuage" width="{guageWidth}" height="{guageHeight}" FCChartType="{guageType}" FCDataXML="{guageXML}" y="0" x="0"/"

when the guageType and the guageXML is the bindable data providers.

when I place this component in first time, the providers don't contain nothing and i let the user to change them in my flex application.
the problem is that when the user change them, the guage doesn't update itself.
I know that when I change a bindable data provider, the component must be changed.
there is any other way to update the component after i change it's data providers?
thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

you should make something like change event handler:

```
public function userChangeHandler(e:Event):void{
    myGuage.FCChartType=changed_FCChartType;
    myGuage.FCDataXML=changed_guageXML;
}
```